# comparing old/new table values

Tags: nodes, theming

I'm building a site which needs the ability to show a daily market values table, that is daily fed by the admins.

The idea is to compare the previous value for each cell and depending on the variation (positive|negative|equal) apply a different color/style to that cell on the output.

Do you know a way to accomplish this requirement without making it from scratch?

Here it is an attachment so you can figure out the expected layout.

[image: table comparison]

Many thanks!!

Comment: *"table, that is daily fed by the admins."* - is it a node? Or what? Because if it's a node, you already have revisions, pretty solid starting point.

Comment: It is pretended to be a node. However all your recommendations are extremely apprecitated!